# Vertically align with translateY(-50%) giving a jerk?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How Can I fix the below code.. I have used the technique of **transform:translateY(-50%)** to make a **div vertically center**. But When I use it with animation , it first takes `top:50%` then it **translates giving a jerk**.. I don't want the jerk to happen and the element should automatically come in center.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #c9edff;
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  Vertical Align is Awesome!
  <br /> But with animation its giving a jerk!<br/> Please Fix
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your animation rule overwrites the `translateY(-50%)` with `scale()`, and when the animation is done, the previous rule gets applied again, hence it jumps.

If you add `translateY(-50%)` to the animation, it will work fine.

*A side note, based on whether one put the `translateY()` before or after the `scale()`, it animates differently, as `transform` values gets applied from right to left*

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #c9edff;
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0); 
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  Vertical Align is Awesome!
  <br /> But with animation its giving a jerk!<br/> Please Fix
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here ist the `line-height`, but you can actually use `calc` to fix that.

`transform: translateY(calc(- 50% + 1.8em));`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #c9edff;
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(calc(- 50% + 1.8em));
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  Vertical Align is Awesome!
  <br /> But with animation its giving a jerk!<br/> Please Fix
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the _jump_ is gone as you compensate for the line-height, but it doesn't center vertically for the same reason